# NaTType does not support isocalendar (just on one particular machine)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, nan

I have a few pythons scripts that run fine, except on one laptop, where they throw this error NaTType does not support isocalendar.
On other laptops they run fine, same version of Python & Pandas*, uninstalled and re-installed Python but still the same.

*Correction: script runs fine on python 3.9.7 but not on 3.10

Any suggestion what to look at next?
Thanks!

Here a snippet of one of the scripts that run fine on other machines, with the same underlying data:

```
145 # create list of lists of values
146 pm01_emea = [pm01_emea.columns.tolist()] + pm01_emea.values.tolist()
147
148 # write the headers and data starting in row 1 (index 0)
149 row = 0
150 for project in (pm01_emea):
151     worksheet0.write_row(row, 0, project)
152     row +=1
```

Here the error it is throwing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\GitHub\pm01\pm01.py", line 151, in <module>
worksheet0.write_row(row, 0, project)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 85, in
cell_wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 1370, in write_row
error = self._write(row, col, token, cell_format)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 508, in _write
return self._write_datetime(row, col, *args)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 1019, in _write_datetime
number = self._convert_date_time(date)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 4320, in _convert_date_time
return datetime_to_excel_datetime(dt_obj,
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\utility.py", line 702, in datetime_to_excel_datetime
and dt_obj.isocalendar() == (1900, 1, 1)):
File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\nattype.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype._make_error_func.f
ValueError: NaTType does not support isocalendar
PS C:\GitHub\pm01>
```

Comment: can you add an example that shows the code that causes the error?

Comment: @FObersteiner we now have the issue on another machine, but can't figure out what is the root cause. I assume it's a date that is passed as a parameter to worksheet.write_row that cannot be treated as a date. Since all dates have the same format, and it works on other machines, I can only assume it's a regional settings (date time format) issue, but we can't find any difference in regional settings between the machines where it works and where not. Any idea? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We've tested changing regional settings and date formats on other machines but can't reproduce it either. Is there some python/pandas/xlsxwriter setup parameter that would determine if NaT is allowed or not? I believe now that it's the first null value in a date column that causes the error, but only on certain machines.

Comment: did you try to write the Excel file directly from pandas? or do you *have* to use a specific excel writer engine?

Comment: I have to use xlsxwriter. I now figured out that the machines where the script fails actually are on Python 3.10, while the scripts run fine on 3.9.7. So it's unlikely a date format or regional settings issue. All dates are in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss so regional settings shouldn't play any role anyway. Shall I try to downgrade to 3.9.7?

Comment: Sounds a bit drastic; but yes, Python 3.10 still has some issues in combination with some 3rd party libs. One more thing you could try on the Python 3.10 machine: upgrade numpy

Comment: I tried updating all the involved packages, but always got 'requirement already fulfilled' so no joy either. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

No solution found other than to uninstall Python 3.10.2 and reinstall 3.9.7 from scratch. Didn't want to go into venv but needed a fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue while using Python version 3.9.6
However, after manually updating numpy and pandas I don't observe the issue anymore:

```
pip freeze | grep -e pandas -e numpy              
numpy==1.22.2
pandas==1.4.1
```

Comment: Thanks, The python 3.10.2 machines are already on numpy 1.22.2 wile the 3.9.7 where the scripts run fine have numpy 1.20.2.